# Write data into csv not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am using Python v2.7.

I have defined a `School` class, it has a method `get_properties_in_array()` which returns an array of its properties:

```
class School:
   def __init__(self, name, address):
       self.name = name
       self.address = address

   def get_properties_in_array(self):
       return [self.name, self.address]
```

I created a school and add it to a list:

```
school_list = []
my_school = School("school-name","school-address")
school_list.append(my_school)
```

Then, I try to write this `my_school` into a CSV file, with properties been tab delimited (I have imported the `csv` module):

```
with open("schools.csv", 'w') as data_file:
     writer = csv.writer(data_file, delimiter='\t')
     for one_school in school_list:
         data = one_school.get_properties_in_array
         # TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
         writer.writerow(data)
```

But when I run it, in the line `writer.writerow(data)` the following error occurs:

```
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Why? How to solve it?

Comment: Missing parenthesis: `data = one_school.get_properties_in_array()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *call the method*:

```
data = one_school.get_properties_in_array()
```